# Why in Jasmine, we cannot put the expect in an outside function?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

If using Jasmine 1.3.1, I use

```
describe("TryTry", function() {

    var i;

    function checkForSituation(a) {
        // say, if this is made into a function because 
        //   there are a lot of processing

        console.log("THERE", a); 
        expect(foo(3, a)).toEqual( 3 + a );
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log("HERE", i); 

        it("should add for " + i, function() {

            checkForSituation(i);

        });

    }

});
```

and foo is just:

```
function foo(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

I would expect it to check for 0 to 4, and print out

```
HERE 0
THERE 0
HERE 1
THERE 1
  ...
```

but instead, it just print in Chrome's console as: `HERE 0, HERE 1, ...` and then `THERE 5` five times.  Does somebody know why an `expect` cannot be put in an outside function like that and what to do in Jasmine if I need to put many steps into a function?

As a side note, sometimes in JavaScript, I feel like a whole new language is developed and what you can usually do won't work -- and wonder what can be done to prevent this type of things from happening, something without knowing that it would happen.

If you'd like to try it out, it is on https://github.com/jianlin/jasmine-looping-an-it-calling-function-that-does-expect

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Jasmine, so I don't know what most of this does, and I definitely don't know what `it` does, but this seems to be the common closure problem in Javascript.

This usually happens when something asynchronous (like an `event` handler) tries to access the iterator (`i`) in its callback. By that time, the loop has finished and `i` is the last value. Using a closure, the value of `i` could be captured and be passed properly. If `it` is asynchronous, you won't be able to get the order of `console.log` results you wanted - the "HERE" will come first, then the "THERE".

You could try this code:

```
it("should add for " + i, (function(i) {
    return function () {
        checkForSituation(i);
    };
})(i);
```

Comment: aha, I suspected that it is a closure thing, but why would an assertion be put into a delayed called mechanism... by the way, if you do that, you are just passing the result of the function instead of a function...

Comment: @動靜能量 Sorry, I just edited the code. I typed quickly and forgot that little part, thanks for reminding me. As for why an assertion is asynchronous, is beyond me. I'll look into the documentation and see if I can find anything about it

Comment: although this can solve the problem, what I am after is really why, and what's the definitive structure or the way it works in Jasmine.  It is also funny that this solution is like, creating a closure to solve another closure problem.